# Is this Name? vs Are you Name?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

My friend requested me to meet him on Skype.
And I searched him on Skype with his ID. The ID is matched but the account name isn't in English.
So, I just want to make sure that he is Peter or not. 
I would like to ask him like

"Is this Peter?" or "Are you Peter?"

Which one is commonly use? 
And what is the differences between these two phrases?

Comment: "Are you Peter?" is ideal. You can also use "Is this Peter?"

Comment: To me both look right. (a learner)

Comment: "it" is almost never used to describe a person. Notable exceptions would be a corpse or a baby of unknown gender, but even in those situations it can come across as inappropriate.  You might say "Is it Peter?" in conversation if you were asking someone to *confirm* a *name*. For example, if you were trying to decipher a name that was handwritten with poor penmanship, or if someone told you their name, but you did not hear it clearly.

Comment: You have edited your question to change *it* to *this*.  "Is this Peter" is perfectly acceptable especially in this context.

Comment: @Nmath That's why I said both look right, suppose something like: "A: Who is this? B: It's Nmath" So, I thought maybe the interrogative sentence is also grammatically and idiomatically correct in some contexts. *shrug*

Comment: "Is this Peter?" is perfect and idiomatic. "Are you Peter?" sounds just a little awkward in this context, but it is not wrong. You would say "Are you Peter?" when directly speaking to a person in your physical presence, but not over the phone, e-mail or chat.

Comment: I would say "Is this Peter" when pointing at someone at a image... or knocking at someone door :-) and say "Are you Peter" when talking to the person that which you think is Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking on the phone it is perfectly OK - and recommended - to use:

> "Is this Peter?"

Of course, it is still understandable if you use other sentences, but they do not sound as English.

If you prefer to be informal, you may use:

> Hello Peter, is that you?

---

Note:

If the Skype account is "Peter", there is a big chance that the person at the other end is a Peter, but you will still not have the certainty that you reached the desired Peter.

To make sure you reached the correct person, ask some key question that a foreigner would not know the answer for. Be careful to **avoid** questions answerable with YES / NO.